# PHP: array declaration causes Error 500

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, http-status-code-500

I encountered a strange problem today: this simple code it's causing error 500.

```
$ret = array();
$ret["lat"] = array():
```

it looks like doing anything wit `$ret` after is has been declared causes the error. I also tried:

```
$ret = array("lat" => array(), "lon" => array());
$ret["lat"][0] = 3:

$ret = array();
$ret["lat"][0] = 3:

$ret = array();
$ret[] = 3:
```

and other stuff I could think of. I've alway did such things, can't understand why it's not working here. Any idea?

Comment: Open your error logs and see what is really wrong

Comment: why there is `:` instead of  `;` to terminate line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove ":" from ends of lines and replace them with ";". Maybe you dont see errors due to a bad configuration of your php.ini file. Try to add this line:

```
`error_reporting(E_ALL);`
```

Comment: oh my god.... I feel so embarassed right now ....

Comment: shouldn't that cause a parse error or something?

Comment: Depends on php.ini configuration of error_reporting

Comment: yes I tried putting error_reporting(E_ALL) but I was still getting the 500 error

Comment: Well, it *is* causing a parse error, which is reported as "500". And because it's a parse error the `error_reporting` call inside the code which has parse errors doesn't do anything…

Answer (score 0):

Remove `:` after `$ret["lat"] = array():` and add `;`

Answer (score 0):

@Jacopo Grassi please remove : and use ; at the place of that like below

```
<?php
$ret = array();
$ret["lat"] = array();
```